# error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: html, reactjs

estoy haciendo un select de esta forma en Reactjs:

```
   let html = `<select name="select" class="select-api" onchange=${self.onChange} value=${self.state.value}>`;
          projectsName.forEach(function(item){
            html += `<option value="${item.value}">${item.value}</option> `;
          })
          html += `</select>`;
          nodo.innerHTML = html
```

al hacer mi onchange, me sale el error de Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, pero no entiendo que es lo que pasa, alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: ¿No usas la sintaxis JSX de React?

Comment: justo en esta parte lo que necesito hacer es de una respuesta de un api, inyectar un select, no se de que otra forma podria meter ese select

Comment: es posible que el error se encuentre en otra parte de tu codigo debido a que `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` ese tipo de errores es al cerrar mal un tag.

Comment: estas trayendo datos desde un backend ?

Comment: guardar html en una variable e inyectarla es de mala practica en react, eso no le vas a ver nunca en codigo react, lo que puedes hacer es crear el componente mediante jsx y luego pasarle los datos que tienes que pasar, puedes usar un .map para ir mapeando y creando selects con distintos valores

Answer (score 0):

te olvidaste de algunas comillas:

```
 let html = `<select name="select" class="select-api" onchange="${self.onChange}" value="${self.state.value}">`;
          projectsName.forEach(function(item){
            html += `<option value="${item.value}">${item.value}</option> `;
          })
          html += `</select>`;
          nodo.innerHTML = html
```

Comment: ya las he agregado pero sigue saliendo el mismo error :(